# how to install appuim in ubuntu. i have following error how to solve this error i am new for nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
leo@leo:~$ sudo npm install -g appium

npm ERR! appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2 install: `node ./bin/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appium-selendroid-driver@1.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the appium-selendroid-driver package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appium-selendroid-driver
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "appium@beta"
npm ERR! cwd /home/leo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I installed nodejs version v0.10.37 also come this error

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have [an outdated version of Node.js](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6276#issuecomment-195603966) (v0.10.37 was released on 2015-03-11). Try [updating your Node.js installation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).